# 2009 Toyota Sienna 146k mi. CEL on 500 mi after “oil change”

Tags: toyota, sienna, timing-chain

Had an oil change done 500 miles ago. About a month of driving very short trips, low speeds, grocery and back
CEL came on last week, had towed to “reputable” place that did the oil change…
They ran codes p0014,15,17 came up.Quoted parts and labor 6k. Timing chain, gears, tensioners, actuator sprocket kit, cylinder head, timing cover, gaskets and fluids.
Told me it’s “drivable” “operable” but not ideal. Drove home 5 miles. Sat in garage for the last week.
I popped the hood over thanksgiving, just looking around— checked dipstick and no oil. A tiny bit of black at bottom tip.
Question 1- Did they forget to change the oil? I did have 2 tires put on, brake light fixed?
Question 2- Did they drain and not refill? Not sure I could’ve driven a month with no oil?
Question 3- Wouldn’t oil be all over my garage/ engine if it had major leaks? Is it possible to burn 6.4 quarts in 500 miles of low speed 5minute trips?
Just trouble shooting no oil on dipstick and all these new issues. Are they negligent or responsible for new engine issues?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Are you sure it is completely devoid of oil? Have you tried bringing it up to level? I'm wondering if they only put 5qts back in during oil change instead of the full 6.4qts. You might try adding a qt and seeing if it comes back up near the "normal" range. If so, all of this *might* be caused from low oil pressure to the exhaust cam VVT phaser.

Comment: You would not be the first horror story of a botched oil change.  But either check that the filter is properly installed, the drain plug is properly installed, and that the oil is properly filled.